# Datagridview Numeric Filter - .net

Tags: .net, vb.net, forms, visual-studio-2008, datagridview

I'm attempting to filter a datagrid based on a column called "Op No#".  When someone puts a value into the textbox I build up a string containing the filter and then apply that to the datagrid (I've omitted that part as it works with other, text,  fields I've tried it on).

The problem I'm encountering is that when I put a number into the textbox and apply the filter it doesn't return any results and I can't see any reason for this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    If MainView.TextBox2.Text <> "" Then
        If MainView.FilterCount = 0 Then
            MainView.FilterStr = "'*[Op No#]*' like '%" & MainView.TextBox2.Text & "%'" : MainView.FilterCount = MainView.FilterCount + 1
        Else
            MainView.FilterStr = MainView.FilterStr & "and" & "'*[Op No#]*' like '%" & Convert.ToInt32(MainView.TextBox2.Text) & "%'" : MainView.FilterCount = MainView.FilterCount + 1
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: Is Mainview the datagridview? If so the statement "Mainview.Textbox2" doesn't make any sense, since that means you're referring to a form called Mainview.

Comment: Sorry, mainview is a userform which contains both the datagridview and the textbox.  The code above is an extract from a separate module hence the necessity to call mainview.

Comment: So, Mainview has this filterstr you set. When do you tell the datagridview to execute the filter str and filter the column?

Comment: Yeah, I store the filterstr as a string within mainview then later on in the module I apply filterstr to the datagridview within mainview.  That works when I filter different columns with text in but it doesn't work when I apply the filter with a number in it.

Comment: okay, you're going to need to include all code that is relevant to your problem. Please enter that. But, if it works with text but not with a number, than there is an issue with your filter string you're creating. What is the value at runtime when you execute the line that applies it to the datagridview? And what's its value when you just use the text?

Answer (score 2):

Your main filter string is wrong from what I can see... change this

```
"'*[Op No#]*' like '%" & MainView.TextBox2.Text & "%'"
```

To this...for numbers only...

```
 "Column name = " & MainView.TextBox2.Text
```

Another Example...

```
 DataView.RowFilter = "Year = 2008"
```

Your filter syntax is wrong and you're doing a like on an integer...your wrapping it in ticks and percent symbols...dont do this.

Also theres a pound symbol after your column and thats fine, just make sure its wrapped in brackets like you have, i didnt show this.

String values are enclosed within single quotes ' '. If the string contains single quote ', the quote must be doubled. Number values are not enclosed within any characters. The values should be the same as is the result of int.ToString() or float.ToString() method for invariant or English culture.

Heres more information...
http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks, yeah my syntax was wrong.  It now reads `MainView.FilterStr = "[Op No#] =" & MainView.TextBox2.Text`  Is it possible though to use a wildcard with the filter as it only shows the results when an exact match is found?

Comment: You need to determine this before hand from my understanding.